# Finding the Energy of the system in a 2d Ising model

Tags: python, montecarlo

I want to ask if my formula for getting the total energy of a system in a 2d Ising Model is correct. The code is shown below. If I'm wrong, can someone please guide me on how to do this properly? Or can someone suggest me to some readings that I can work on to better understand this topic?

Also, I would like to ask if it is also correct that by getting the modulo of i+1, i-1, j+1, and j-1, we get to treat the lattice as a toroidal? This would help me a lot, thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# creating a NxN array that consists of +1 and -1 values
def lattice(N): 
    spin_state = np.random.choice([-1,1],size=(N,N))
    return spin_state

# calculating the energy
def total_energy(system):
    energy = 0
    for i in range(len(system)):
        for j in range(len(system)):
            spin = system[i,j]
            neighbor = system[(i+1)%N, j] + system[i,(j+1)%N] + system[(i-1)%N, j] + system[i,(j-1)%N]
            energy += -neighbor*spin
    return energy/4.

system = lattice(N)
```

Comment: You probably have certain expectations of what the results should be. Start by verifying for small N, e.g. 2 => does the result match your expectation? What about N=3? If you have 3x3 lattice in a toroidal geometry, which neighbors do you expect? Is that what your code gives you? Add some print statements to better understand what's going on, e.g. `print(f"Neighbors of (i,j)={(i,j)}: ({(i+1)%N, j}), ...")`.

Comment: I'm just confused on what to return because I keep on seeing formats where it returns 2*energy or energy/4.